# Access query where criteria is Like Table1.Field but Field is a string type that contains "*"

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a select query in access where column Table2.FullNameField criteria is "Like Table1.ShortNameField". So the record is selected if Table2.FullNameField contains Table1.ShortNameField. Both fields are strings. The problem is the names contain an *. Here's an example:

ShortNameField = "A*01"

FullNameField = "A*01:04", "A*15:01", "A*03:02", etc

Query criteria = "Like Table1.ShortNameField" => Like A*01 (where * is interpreted as wild card)

The expected/desired result for the ShortNameField above would be to select the record with FullNameField of "A*01:04" but instead I'm getting the record with "A*15:01".

So the question is how do I get the Like function to treat the * in the short name as a character of the string and not a wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider replacing the character:

```
SELECT  t.shortnamefield, t.fullnamefield
FROM Table t
WHERE Replace([fullnamefield],"*","|") 
     Like "*" & Replace([shortnamefield],"*","|") & "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

To escape special characters in LIKE clauses, the general rule is to enclose the character in [], e.g.[*] and [?].

Example:

```
select * from x where y like "[*]*"
```

will give you all records from table x where the y field starts with an asterisk (*).